# How to mock the useApolloClient hook?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-testing

Apollo Client provides [this doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/) for testing APIs with `MockedProvider`, but it doesn't seem to mock the `useApolloClient` hook. When I use MockedProvider with my functional component and run the test, I get this error even though I've added MockedProvider while mounting:

```
Invariant Violation: No Apollo Client instance can be found. Please ensure that you have called `ApolloProvider` higher up in your tree.

      72 |   );
      73 |
    > 74 |   const makeCall = useApolloClient();
```

This is how I mounted it:

```
const mockResponses = [];
const wrapper = mount(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mockResponses} addTypename={false}>
      <Provider store={store}>
          <PriceComponent
            ...someProps
          />
      </Provider>
    </MockedProvider>
  );
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you create a wrapper for this so it can be re-used where needed.

```
import { MockedProvider, MockedResponse } from "@apollo/client/testing";
import { render, RenderResult } from "@testing-library/react";
import { FC, ReactElement } from "react";

function renderWithApolloProvider(
  ui: ReactElement,
  mocks: MockedResponse<Record<string, any>>[] = [],
): RenderResult {
  const Wrapper: FC = ({ children }) => {
      return (
          <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
              {children}
          </MockedProvider>
      );
  };

  return render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper });
};
```

Then you can use it in your tests like this:

```
const mocks = [
  // Your GraphQL mocks
];

renderWithApolloProvider(
  <PriceComponent
     ...someProps
  />,
  mocks
);
```

> I used the react testing library for the example above.

You seem to be using `enzyme` to test your components so try this

```
function mountWithApolloProvider(
    Component,
    mocks = [],
) {
  const wrapper = mount(
     <Provider store={store}>
       <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
          <Component />
       </MockedProvider>
     </Provider>
  )
  return wrapper;
}
```

Usage:

```
const mocks = [
  // Your GraphQL mocks
];

renderWithApolloProvider(
  PriceComponent,
  mocks
);
```